# Disable Single-Select query drop drown based on value in the list-JasperServer

Tags: javascript, java, jasperserver

We are using JasperReports Server Community Edition 5.5 and have a problem with a Single-Select Query.

[image]
I have a custom need to disable the input drop down if we have the one vale in the drop down and if the drop down is having multiple value then it has to a drop down to select from the listed value.

Could you please how I can achive the same using the jasper or Java code.

Comment: Do you have access to the computer in which Jasper Report Server is installed?

Comment: Yes It is.I have deleted the drop down values.

Comment: If so, create another Input Control which counts the value of the above mentioned drop down. And then you can disable and enable the input controls by using JSP based on the count value. For more info refer http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-ultimate-guide/v55/customizing-user-interface

Comment: I am new to tech could you please provide me any kind of good tutorial related to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Inorder to enable or disable the input controls based on the count of values in it, you need to approach the help of JSP in Jasper Server system.

The main approach is to

1. Create an another input control which counts the number of values.
2. Then using JSP, enable or disable the input control based on the
   count.
3. Then finally specify that jsp as `optional jsp location` in report settings of Jasper Server. Refer highlighted portion in the below image

[image]

If you are using `pop-up` input control then you can find the JSP file in location `<js-webapp>/WEB-INF/jsp/modules/inputControls/DefaultParametersForm.jsp`.

If you are using `In-Page`, then location is `<js-webapp>/WEB-INF/jsp/templates/inputControls.jsp`.

Make a copy of the jsp file to another location say `<js-webapp>/WEB-INF/jsp/custom` file.

You can [refer this blog which hides the input control](http://helicaltech.com/how-to-hide-input-controls-from-the-jasperserver-using-optional-jsp/) .

You can make use of it and modify according to your need.

Hope this should help you out.